# Django Rest Framework - ForeignKey filtering in a serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, `Fridge` and `Product`. `Fridge` has a ForeignKey to `auth.user`, while `Product` has a ForeignKey to `Fridge`, simple enough.

Now quite obviously, I want an user to be able to add products only to his fridge. I want to create an API for that using DRF, AND I want a nice dropdown in the product viewset form, hence why I have to do this in a serializer. I'm using `viewsets.ViewSet` class, so `get_serializer_context` doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    fridge = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=WHAT_QUERYSET)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=Product._meta.get_field('name').max_length)
    purchase_date = serializers.DateField()
    before_date = serializers.DateField()
```

I have no idea what should I put in the `queryset` keyword argument for the `fridge` attribute. I can't ask for `request.user` anywhere in that scope, as no context or request variables exist at that point.

Comment: Why did you mark an answer as correct but then comment that it doesn't work? :-S Did you find a working solution? If so, please share it.

Comment: By the way, while it is certainly possible to get the fridge and user details into the serializer the way I solve this is by setting them prior to saving in the viewset (in perform_create). That way the request is simply to 'add a product' and it can only be added to the users fridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is dynamically queryset based on the user that makes the request. You can achieve this by overriding the `__init__` method like this:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request_user = self.context['request'].user
        self.fields['fridge'].queryset = Fridge.objects.filter(user=request_user)
```

The initial field will have to look like this, since you have to specify the queryset othewise you will get an AssertionError:

```
    fridge = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Fridge.objects.all())
```

but this will be overridden of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but unfortunatelly that doesn't work.

First of all, if I use `viewsets.ViewSet` as my base class, then the serializer class get's initialized twice - one time by me explicitly, and just before that by ViewSet. And the `request` object doesn't get passed in the context to that first initialization.

If I check for request being set and only then modify the queryset, then I'm able to add products to other people fridges.

This is what I tried already: https://dpaste.de/AWRu